# Is there a way to link libraries in a visual studio 2015 remote linux application?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 on windows to develop a c++ application for a linux machine using the linux project template. So far I have built the libraries I need on the remote machine, then transferred those libraries to my windows machine.

From there I have included them in my project as normal (in the project properties), but there are still some errors when I am building the project, as far as I can tell they are link errors. I am fairly certain I have included all the necessary files and linked everything correctly within the IDE.

This is purely for fun and a learning experience for me, so please forgive me if I am way off base here. I have read about makefiles but am still new to linux development and was just wondering if anyone has any experience with this.

If this cant be done remotely from within the visual studio IDE I would love to hear suggestions.

EDIT: It seems I was mistaken about what it was exactly that I am trying to do, sorry guys.

Comment: You should post the errors you are getting

Comment: It seems you are trying to locally compile and/or link a code that you intend to run in the remote linux. You need a cross-compiler for that. But ff you are trying to locally link remotely compiled object files `*.o` into windows executable, that will not work at all, even with cross-compilers. The object files `*.o` that were compiled from remote linux will have references to linux libraries of which some are exclusive. The local linker will not find these exclusive linux libraries that are referenced by these object files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot link libraries on Windows with MSVC compiler that you compiled on your remote Linux machine with a different compiler. You will need to recompile them.

Comment: I was under the impression that visual studio will just invoke the compiler on my remote machine to build the project there after it is copied using the g++ compiler.

Comment: @EthanMorris I may have misunderstood you. This is how I got you: you compile the libraries on your remote Linux machine, and try to link them without recompiling on your Windows machine?